# Get all cards in carousel displayed in single row for lower screen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am working on carousel which has 4 cards in total and displays 2 images per slide. But when screen size is minimized I get card in two rows stacked one upon other. Is there a way to get all the cards in single row with one card per slide for smaller screen?

```
<div class="carouselBox">
 <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner mr-0">
    <div class="carousel-item active col-12 col-md-6">
      <div class="row productFlex">
        <div class="box">
          <div class="card">
           
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item col-12 col-md-6">
      <div class="row productFlex">
        <div class="box">
          <div class="card">
            
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
```

And below is the CSS

```
.box{
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; 
       flex-wrap: nowrap;  
        padding: 1rem;
        min-height: 434px;
        
    }

    .box > .card{
        margin-left:1rem;
        margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
        min-width: 100%;
    }
    .card{
        background: var(--unnamed-color-113052) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
        background: #113052 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
        flex: 48%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: Please attach your CSS

Comment: I have attached the CSS for your reference

Comment: Yes, there is. But it will require JavaScript to determine how many cards should be displayed per screen size in a slide and will re-render the contents of the slides.

Comment: Your 1st `.carousel-item` has classes `col-12 md-6`. Do you mean `col-12 col-md-6`? Also, your 2nd `.carousel-item` also has class `col-12-md-6`. Shouldn't that be `col-12 col-md-6`?

Comment: _"But when screen size is minimized I get card in two rows stacked one upon other."_ I am not seeing this behavior. " _Is there a way to get all the cards in single row with one card per slide for smaller screen?"_ This sentence is not clear.

Comment: When I change my screen size to small, two cards from same slide are displayed in two rows while in bigger screen, two cards from same slide are displayed in single row.

So for smaller screen size can I display one card per slide?

Comment: You can do that by changing the structure of your slides. You'll have to move around / remove / create slides based on size of the screen.